# Shell script in rosdep rule error

Tags: ros, rosdep, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Update** The similar error happens even with the rule that's already commited. For example on Ubuntu, add `glc` ([link to rosdep rule](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/dbfca533c653b3208f0a1dffa4ae7fe21cac25aa/rosdep/base.yaml#L565)) as dependency in package.xml and `rosdep` your package (in my case I arbitrarily used rqt_plot again). Should I open a ticket?

```
$ rosdep install rqt_plot -s
#[apt] Installation commands:
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt-gui
  sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
  sudo apt-get install update
sudo
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt-py-common
  sudo apt-get install ppa:arand
sudo
  sudo apt-get install sudo
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rostopic
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-qt-gui-py-common
  sudo apt-get install python-rospkg
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt-gui-py
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosgraph
  sudo apt-get install install
  sudo apt-get install #!/bin/bash
yes
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-catkin
  sudo apt-get install glc

  sudo apt-get install python-qwt5-qt4
  sudo apt-get install -y
  sudo apt-get install |
  sudo apt-get install apt-add-repository
  sudo apt-get install apt-get
```

package.xml

```
  :
  <run_depend>glc</run_depend>
  :
```

---

**Initial post**

Embedding a shell script into `rosdep` rule, then `rosdep install rqt_plot` returns the following and obviously fails. What is wrong?

```
executing command [sudo apt-get install then
]
```

The following seems all what happens. Looks entirely corrupted:

```
$ rosdep install rqt_plot -s
#[apt] Installation commands:
  sudo apt-get install then

  sudo apt-get install 
  sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
  sudo apt-get install -i
  sudo apt-get install sudo
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rostopic
  sudo apt-get install cd
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt-gui
  sudo apt-get install fi

  sudo apt-get install if
  sudo apt-get install !
  sudo apt-get install -f
  sudo apt-get install #!/bin/bash
if
  sudo apt-get install ]
  sudo apt-get install mkdir
  sudo apt-get install -p
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt-py-common
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-catkin
  sudo apt-get install ;
  sudo apt-get install /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyqtgraph
  sudo apt-get install ~/.ros/rosdep/tmp
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt-gui-py
  sudo apt-get install python-rospkg
  sudo apt-get install ~/.ros/rosdep/tmp

  sudo apt-get install http://www.pyqtgraph.org/downloads/python-pyqtgraph_0.9.7-1_all.deb

  sudo apt-get install wget
  sudo apt-get install [
  sudo apt-get install python-qwt5-qt4
  sudo apt-get install python-pyqtgraph_0.9.7-1_all.deb
fi

  sudo apt-get install dpkg
  sudo apt-get install --tries=10
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-qt-gui-py-common
  sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosgraph
```

Script looks as follows ([link to repo](https://github.com/130s/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml#L15)), or I tried [several changes. See Aug 06 2013 for them](https://github.com/130s/rosdistro/commits/master):

```
pyqtgraph:
  debian: []
  ubuntu: |
    #!/bin/bash
    if [ ! -f /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyqtgraph ] ; then
      if [ ! -f ~/.ros/rosdep/tmp ] ; then
        mkdir -p ~/.ros/rosdep/tmp
      fi
      cd ~/.ros/rosdep/tmp
      wget --tries=10 http://www.pyqtgraph.org/downloads/python-pyqtgraph_0.9.7-1_all.deb
      sudo dpkg -i python-pyqtgraph_0.9.7-1_all.deb
    fi
```

This piece of script (from `shebang` until `fi`) runs fine and does what it's supposed to do when I give it to terminal.

I added the following in the `package.xml` needless to mention.

```
  <run_depend>pyqtgraph</run_depend>
```

Also modified is this:

```
$ more /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
# os-specific listings first
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml gentoo

# generic
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
## yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
yaml https://github.com/130s/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
```

And did `rosdep update`. I also removed `20-default.list` and did `rosdep update` but no luck.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71581/shell-script-in-rosdep-rule-error/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bash scripts are not supported in Fuerte and newer: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0111.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0